# Reducing integral in factor graph

Tags: integration

I have one question about reducing integral in factor graph. Applying message passing algorithm, I have create a final integral

$g(z) = \int_x \int_y f(x, y , z) f_1(x) f_2(y) dx dy$

with the condition that

$f(x, y, z) = 1$ when x + y = z and 0 otherwise. Moreover, $x,y \in R$

I wonder whether the above integral is equal to

$g(z) = \int_x f_1(x) f_2(z - x) dx$

One of my friend say that the $\int_x \int_y ...$ is equal to $0$ but I dont think so. Would you please help me to solve this problem.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $y$ integral is indeed zero, because the range in $y$ is from $z-x$ to $z-x$.  Your integral is trying to measure an area and the second is a one-dimensional line.  Maybe instead you want $f(x,y,z)=\delta(z-x-y)$, the [Dirac "delta function"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function).  It allows the transformation to the last, because it is "infinitely high" when $x+y=z$ to get you the extra dimension you need.

Comment: Hi, I just want to ask one more simple question. If I replace my function $f(x, y, z)$ by the Dirac "delta function", would I derive the equation of 2 kinds of integral.

Comment: @Nam:  Yes, then you can go to the second integral for $g(z)$.  Essentially the "delta function" picks out the value where the argument is zero.